# Converting to sql style string

Tags: python

I have 3 variables:

```
var1="abc"
var2="def"
sqlPrefix = "select x,y in myTable where myVar in "
```

I want to create a string of `('abc','def')`, so I can directly concatenate that to the end of `sqlPrefx`, so my final string is `select x,y in myTable where myVar in ('abc','def')`

Comment: Use SQL parameters; do not interpolate values into the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, in order to avoid sql injections you shouldn't construct sql queries manually like this.

But, just FYI, here's how you <strike>can</strike> shouldn't do it:

```
sqlPrefix = "select x,y in myTable where myVar in ('%s', '%s')" % (var1, var2)
```

Also, see: [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Comment: I'd say **mustn't** instead of **shouldn't**